# Reference vs. Precise Reference in Dalvik Verifier

Tags: android, bytecode, dalvik, bytecode-manipulation, smali

I am writing instrumentation on Dalvik bytecode which performs some logging for various method call entries. Specifically, at various method call sites, I will insert a set of instructions which collects up the parameters, puts them in an `Object[]` array, and then passes that to a logging function.

This is all fine and well, I have implemented and gotten past all of the kludges for most apps. But I'm encountering one particularly impenetrable Dalvik verifier error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class io.a.a.g: void io.a.a.g.r() 
failed to verify: void io.a.a.g.r(): [0x570] register v5 has type Reference: 
java.lang.Object but expected Precise Reference: java.lang.String
```

I looked at the code that is being generated by my instrumentation, and all I'm doing is putting register v5 in an array of objects.

I have a few questions here:

- What is a *precise* reference, and why is it incompatible with references?
- What does the offset here mean? `[0x570]` points into the middle of a bytecode instruction, so it doesn't clearly map to any instructions: the instructions around there don't involve `v5`.
- How would I go about debugging this? Ideally, I'd like to know what the verifier thinks should be happening and fix that.

EDIT:

Here's a dump of the bytecode of the method I'm speaking about. https://gist.github.com/kmicinski/c8382f0521b19643bb24379d91c47d36 As you can see, 0x570 isn't the beginning of an instruction, and (as far as I can tell) there isn't any place where r5 conflicts with a String where it should be an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely at the error, it is telling you that you're passing an `Object`, where a `String` is expected. Anyway, there isn't much more that can be said unless you post the actual bytecode that is causing the problem.

Are you sure that 0x570 points to the middle of an instruction? It shouldn't. Anyway, the way you would go about debugging it is to look at the relevant instruction and figure out why r5 is an Object when it's supposed to be a String. Or you could post the bytecode so I could take a look.

Edit: Now that you've posted the code, there is in fact a path which results in v5 being Object, but it is a bit subtle

The exception handler 
`.catch JSONException {:5D8 .. :938} :BDE` jumps to :BDE

The code for the exception handler stores the caught exception in v5, meaning that v5 is no longer a String at this point. It then jumps to `:162`

```
:BDE
00000BDE  move-exception      v5
00000BE0  const               v0, 0x00488B36
00000BE6  invoke-static       Logger->logBasicBlockEntry(I)V, v0
00000BEC  goto/16             :162
```

`:162` is within the range of another exception handler: `.catch ClassNotFoundException {:2E .. :594} :BF0`

`:Bf0` leaves v5 untouched and jumps to `:A28`

```
:BF0
00000BF0  move-exception      v6
00000BF2  const               v0, 0x00488B3E
00000BF8  invoke-static       Logger->logBasicBlockEntry(I)V, v0
00000BFE  goto/16             :A28
```

`:A28` is the beginning of a code block which assumes that v5 is String. In particular, on instruction `:AE0`, v5 is passed to a function taking a String.

```
00000AE0  invoke-virtual      StringBuilder->append(String)StringBuilder, v7, v5
```

0xAE0 is exactly twice 0x570, which explains the offset shown in the error, once you adjust for code units as JesusFreke suggested.

Note that this isn't necessarily the only broken code path, it's just the first one I found while looking through your code. However, one bad path is sufficient to unify v5's type with JSONException and hence turn it into Object.

Comment: Here's a dump of the bytecode, done via JEB: https://gist.github.com/kmicinski/c8382f0521b19643bb24379d91c47d36 
As you can see, 0x570 isn't something that exists as the start of a bytecode instruction. Additionally, as far as I can tell, `r5` isn't being used in an incorrect way anywhere within this method (although the control flow is slightly challenging, which is why having a precise error index would help)

Comment: @KristopherMicinski I edited my post with an example of control flow that improperly results in v5 being a non-String object.

Comment: thanks a ton! Wow, you really went above and beyond, that code is really challenging to interpret. I will definitely look through this and accept your answer..

Answer (score 3):

0x570 is likely the offset in code units, which are two bytes each. So the byte offset is actually 0xAE0, which does correspond with an instruction, and that instruction does reference v5.

I expect what's happening is that there is code somewhere that stores a string in v5, but there's another code path that merges in between where the string is stored in v5 and where it's used, and that code path has a different object type stored in v5. When the code paths merge, it uses the common superclass of the two types as the type of the register. So if the two types are completely unrelated, java.lang.Object will be the superclass.

What you can do to debug this issue is run baksmali using the `--register-info ARGS,DEST,FULLMERGE` option (and also `--code-offsets`, so you can find 0xAE0 easily), and then look backwards from 0xAE0 and see where the type of v5 is set to be an Object.

Comment: If you can post the baksmali disassembly with the register info as mentioned in my answer, I can take a look. Or rather show you what to look for :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, @JesusFreke. I actually have a control flow analysis that helps highlight these things, so knowing the code offset items is what I was really looking for! (I will look into this and get back to you..!)

Comment: The non-string object is coming from an exception handler which stores the exception in v5 and then eventually reaches AE0 without reassigning v5. See my post for details.

Comment: Hi @JesusFreke and @Antimony! I wish I could accept both your answers'! I updated my post with an answer describing what was eventually the problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add my answer, since others have been so helpful in donating their time to answer a tricky question that probably doesn't generalize much!

As @Antimony points out, there was a control path in my code that began at an exception handler, stored the exception in `v5` (causing `v5` to be an `Object`) and then `goto`'d a point *within* an exception handler. That exception handler then caused `v5` to be used as a string, causing the verifier error.

In the app's original code, the only thin at the target of that `goto` was a `return-void` instruction. Because of this, the Dalvik verifier did not propagate the path through to the exception handler.

Unfortunately, when I rewrote this app, it caused the target of that exception handler to contain more than just this `return-void` instruction, making the verification reason through that block and into the caught exception handler. In particular, before the `return-void`, I inserted a call to `Logger.logMethodExit`, which the verifier then assumes could transfer control back to an exception handler (`:BF0` in this case) and eventually to the place where `v5` was used as a string. In the original app, it was killed (in the gen/kill dataflow sense). But upon rewriting, I included this extra invocation breaking the dataflow invariants... Crud.

I think I know how to fix this in my implementation, but it was sure a pain to figure out!

More general lessons learned here:

- Verifier error offsets are really just 2*index within bytecode
- Unlike JVM bytecode, Dalvik bytecode considers a subset of opcodes non-throwable, including `return`. This will affect dataflow analysis
- Precise reference means something is constrained to be a particular refinement of Object in one basic block, and an `Object` in another (though this error seems a little esoteric to me..)
- When you rewrite bytecode you need to be cognizant of the gen/kill sets you're implicitly working around, and in particular the `return-*` instructions will immediately kill things, whereas jumping to the beginning of a basic block within a `try..` will continue to keep those things live.

Comment: Interesting that you ran into this corner case. In Java bytecode, every instruction is considered to potentially throw, including return. However, Dalvik tries to be smarter, and declares that only a subset of opcodes can throw. I don't remember the list offhand, but apparently, returns are considered non-throwing.

Comment: Do you happen to remember how you figured this out? Was it just via reading the compiler source? I've read some, but not to the extent you apparently have so your input was absolutely helpful :-) Don't how I would have figured this out otherwise.

Comment: I had run into this (only certain instructions can throw) when reading through the dalvik bytecode verifier, while attempting to mimic its register type inference logic, while implementing the deodexing functionality of baksmali. See, e.g. the "throw" instruction flag in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/opcode-gen/bytecode.txt

Comment: @JesusFreke yeah, I maintain Redexer (https://github.com/plum-umd/redexer), which is an OCaml implementation that mimics Baksmali. It also does register reallocation for heavyweight binary instrumentation that mess up typed instructions (though perhaps Baksmali does this now too). I'm glad you point this out, since it implies that our tool is also likely broken

Comment: Yeah, I've considered implementing something like that, but never have. I'm sure it would be quite useful when you need to increase the register size while instrumenting the code. Manually increasing the register count can be quite tricky, especially with parameter registers and the v0-v15 register limitations of some instructions, as I'm sure you know :)

Comment: @JesusFreke that's right! Our tool correctly instruments (in a major way, we're logging most method calls / returns / basic block entries) pretty large apps (currently running on Snapchat!). I'm glad we were able to implement this feature, but sad we duplicated the work Baksmali did. I might switch to that tool going forward with our work (and if so I'll implement that pass in Baksmali)